# how do i update version for super skeleton

Tags: images

how do i update version for super skeleton. I have Version 1.8.0 and noticed that there is a updated version. I looked in the available themes and didn't see the super skeleton theme listed. The reason I want to update is my gallery gets an error message when i click the image "Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist." the gallery settings link to media files but doesn't fix the problem.

sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

The Super Skeleton wordpress theme appears to be a paid theme from Themeforest http://themeforest.net/item/super-skeleton-wp-responsive-minimal-beautiful/647570 so you may want to contact the developer of that theme for an updated copy if they are not offering automatic updates.

You should be careful with updating the theme though because if it does not use child themes, you may overwrite any custom changes you made to the theme.

It might be better for you to post details on the error you are receiving and see if someone can assist with that.  It may not be related to the theme itself, or it could be something that you caused by editing the theme.

Comment: thanks gteh, I'll take your advise about the update. I just want to be able to press the gallery thumbnail and have it show the larger image. I'm not a coder and have to much on my plate at the moment to try and learn. It's probably user error on my part, frustrating.